# Screwturn Wiki Setup, 500.19 error

Tags: wiki, screwturn

I'm currently in the process of setting up Screwturn to host docs for our IT dept.

Windows Server 2008 R2, 
IIS 7.5, 
Application Pool is under v4.0, 
.NET FW 3.5 is installed.

However i have run into the following error;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIRci.png

(I can't post images)

Has anyone else ran into this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Set your .NET FW version to v2.0.  v4.0 doesn't work.

Comment: Extended answer: .net 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 are all FrameWork 2.0; .net 4.0 and 4.5 are FW 4

Comment: v4 does work with version 4 of screw turn wiki the current stable though required version 2 as said in this answer.